# Error 1054 (45S22): Uknown column 'jeff' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add to mysql database. I created the database, and gave it a table. When I try to insert into the table, I get an error. Error 1054 (45S22): Uknown column 'jeff' in 'field list'.
 Here is how I am trying to insert into the table. Both user name and char are varchar(30), NOT NULL:

```
INSERT INTO authentication(usr, pwd)
  VALUES(Jeff, Isthisthe1);
```

Comment: Try putting quotation marks around the values.

Comment: I tried that and it still didn't work. I have tried single and double quotes.

Comment: Not question marks, quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back tics on column and table names, single or double quotes on data values (strings).

```
INSERT INTO `authentication` (`usr`, `pwd`)
  VALUES("Jeff", "Isthisthe1");
```

Comment: Thank you! i don't know why this wasn't an issue when I was working on it a couple months ago.